# How to detect scroll event on angular material 2 autocomplete list using CdkScrollable

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to use `cdkScrollable` to listen`ScrollEvent` on `mat-autocomplete`.

I have implemented like below code snippets.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Notebook Page" formControlName="notebookPage" [matAutocomplete]="NBPageAutocomplete" >
</mat-form-field>
<mat-autocomplete  #NBPageAutocomplete="matAutocomplete" cdkScrollable >
  <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of suggestedNBPageNames" [value]="option">
                {{ option }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

```js
constructor(public scroll: ScrollDispatcher) {}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.scroll.scrolled().subscribe((data: CdkScrollable) => {
       console.log(data);
      //make an HTTP call when it reaches to the end, to add some more data
    });
  }
```

The event was not firing after subscribing to `this.scroll.scrolled()`.

I have been struct on this issue from past few days, didn't find any related info online.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the angular material library, in order to avoid continuous change detection for scroll event, the "scrolled" events emitted will be run outside angular zone by default. For change detection to work, add ngZone.run as below. Please modify the callback in ngZone.run as required.

```js
constructor(public scroll: ScrollDispatcher, private ngZone: NgZone) {}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.scroll.scrolled().subscribe((data: CdkScrollable) => {
       console.log(data);
      //make an HTTP call when it reaches to the end, to add some more data
    });
    ngZone.run(() => {
       console.log('to run change detection');
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find you answer here : [Angular virtual scroll: append new items when reaching the end of scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770671/angular-virtual-scroll-append-new-items-when-reaching-the-end-of-scroll)

Sounds like it is exactly the behavior you're looking for, but you might need to adapt it, depending on the angular version you're using